# How and where should I define types for an SDK / wrapper of a third party API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

I'm writing an SDK for an API that doesn't currently have one. I want to write it in TypeScript to make it easier to use, but I'm struggling with how and where to documents the types for the values the API returns.

For example, the endpoint `/accountInfo` returns an object with ~40 properties, some of which are arrays of objects that could have their own interfaces. Defining these types right in my `.ts` file feels very messy, but I can't figure out the right place to create them. I went down the path of creating a `.d.ts` file, with a namespace for each endpoint, but I can't figure out how to properly import those types and use them. I see a lot of people saying you shouldn't be writing your own `.d.ts` definitions unless you're writing them for a JS module... but is this kind of the equivalent?

Any advice on how to implement types for this kind of project is appreciated.